# Are netty and comet related somehow?

Tags: java, comet, netty

A little confused, how are **netty** and **comet** related or are they seperate and they work together somehow?

I've read a bit about using **netty** and **comet** to build real-time applications, confused how they work together.

Comment: Pretty sure comet is an idea, a way of doing "reverse ajax". And netty is an implementation of this "idea".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, Netty is a framework/library, while Comet is a concept (sort of one-way websockets, and as Chad said, a kind of "reverse ajax").

Comment: Although the new form of functionality, eventually [termed as Comet](http://infrequently.org/2006/03/comet-low-latency-data-for-the-browser/), was push from server to client the requirement for client to server communication was still present. This is was generally achieved in Comet HTTP transports using a 2nd HTTP connection. The streaming/polling server -> client connection has been known as the back channel and the client -> server (standard) communication is sometimes referred to as the command channel; for achieving things like subscripions.

Answer (score 1):

Cometd is an implementation of the Bayeux Protocol (http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html)  This protocol has multiple implementations, of which cometd is likely the most popular.

The point of a Bayeux implementation is that it allows the server to do asynchronous messaging over HTTP that includes the elusive "server push".  Instead of the client polling every, say, 5 seconds, to the server for updates, the server can "call" the client when it has an update.

It uses the technique of Long Polling.  Essentially, an HTTP connection is held open between the client and server.  When the server finally has something to "tell" the client, it responds to the open connection.  The connection, or "long poll" is immediately reestablished.  To prevent HTTP Timeouts, the connection can be automatically re-establised over various time periods.

I'm not exactly sure what the relationsh9ip between Netty and Cometd is, or if there is one.  I suspect Netty would be very useful in implementing the Bayeux Protocol (the documentation seems to hint at this) because one of the weaknesses of the Bayeux Protocol and scaling is the sheer volume of open HTTP Connections that must be handled.  If they block, you have a problem because that's too many threads.